# Filling columns with formula based on another Cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently sending my formula to column K & L based on a user form. It sends the formula based on Column G's input. I want to send the formula to columns K & L only if G has a value in it. Can any one help me?

[picture of datasheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7nU3G.jpg)

```
    'Sets Columns K & L to Method 6 Formula and looks for last populated row in the Nominal Column (G)
    LastRow = Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Range("K7").Formula = "=M7+(Q7*(1.04-EXP(0.38*(LN(P7))-0.54)))"
    Range("L7").Formula = "=N7-(Q7*(1.04-EXP(0.38*(LN(P7))-0.54)))"

    If LastRow = 7 Then
    Else
    Range("K7").AutoFill Destination:=Range("K7:K" & LastRow)
    Range("L7").AutoFill Destination:=Range("L7:L" & LastRow)

    End If
```

Comment: Then check if `G` has a value? What have you tried? Could be as simple as `If Range("G1").Value <> "" Then [do things]`?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean only run the code if G has at least one non-blank cell you could use this. You can apply the formulae across the whole range in one go.

```
Sub x()

Dim LastRow As Long

LastRow = Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Range("K7:K" & LastRow).Formula = "=IF(G7="""", """",M7+(Q7*(1.04-EXP(0.38*(LN(P7))-0.54))))"
Range("L7:L" & LastRow).Formula = "=IF(G7="""", """",N7-(Q7*(1.04-EXP(0.38*(LN(P7))-0.54))))"

End Sub
```

Comment: I want it to run the code only if G has a value If G1, G2, and G3 have a value but G4 and G5 have no value , but G6 G7 G8 have a value push the formula to the G cells that have a value. I added a picture to the original post for clarification

Comment: What is the significance of row 7? Why not add an IF clause at the beginning of the formula to check if the corresponding G cell is blank?

Comment: Row 7 is where the data is being entered everything above row 7 is header information

Comment: And my other question?

Comment: That is what I am trying to do if the Corresponding G cell is blank do not insert the formula. Just having an issue setting it up.

Comment: It wasn't really clear what you were asking, but try the amended code above.